# How to auto update a read-only workbook/sheet, only when the original file is updated?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Hi I am a newbie to programming. I am currently learning python.  We have a excel spreadsheet that is on a network drive that is updated from time to time by any of our users.  A copy of the spreadsheet is open as read only and displayed on a big screen for everyone to see.  I want the read only spreadsheet to auto update itself anytime anyone makes changes to original copy.

I have try to do this as a macro but i find it very limiting and of course I am a newbie so my knowledge is limited.  I am currently learning python and I find they have the libraries that can make this happen.  Can anyone please give me some pointers to lead me on the right track?

I am thinking I will need to poll the original file to see if it was modified. And if it is, find a way to refresh the read only copy if that is possible, or worst case just close and reopen the spreadsheet.  Another way perhaps is to extract the worksheet from the original file (including the formatting) and display it on a webpage.  And of course I am open to any macro vb solutions if anyone has them.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your general plan is reasonable, but... we are here to fix problem on existing code, not to write it or to get into long discussions of how to do it. This question is too broad for this site. Good luck!

Comment: to know if file changed you can compare `shasum filename.xls` with `shasum` run on previous file. or maybe even better make the read only copy a sof link to the original with `ls -s /path/to/original /path/to/link` . About refreshing excel i really don't know... Anyway please provide more info as what operation system is used where files stored e.t.c

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/refresh-an-external-data-connection-in-excel-1524175f-777a-48fc-8fc7-c8514b984440?ocmsassetID=HA010105474&CorrelationId=50022582-0fba-4b1b-aa86-28c737cec251&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) might help, especially the part `Automatically refresh data at regular intervals`